# Delete .csv-column without losing format

Tags: excel, csv, unix, utf-8

My file got the format **Unix (LF) with UTF-8-BOM**. It got quotation marks on each column:

[image]

Now i want to delete the last column. If i save the file with excel as .csv it is formatted in **Windows (CR LF) in ANSI**. It loses the quotation marks:

[image]

I wrote a short C# code to remove the last column manually with StreamReader/StreamWriter, but the output is also formatted in **Windows (CR LF) UTF-8**. Curiously it additionally loses some lines..

```
string newFilename = tboxFile.Text.Split(new string[] { ".csv" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0] + "_replaced123.csv";

StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(tboxFile.Text);
StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(newFilename);

string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
streamWriter.WriteLine(line.Split(new string[] { ";\"@timestamp\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0]);

while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    streamWriter.WriteLine(line.Split(new string[] { ";\"2017-11-" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0]);
```

So.. Is there a special excel-trick to save the output in same format (Unix LF UTF-8-BOM) or how can i help me?

Comment: You could try the spreadsheet tool from LibreOffice. If you **Save As** a csv with it, there is a check box "Edit filter settings" (or something with that meaning). With this enabled a "Textexport" dialog (where you can select the text codec) will show up after you press Save.

Comment: Write that as answer please, markus. So i can accept it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like my comment above says, the spreadsheet tool from LibreOffice offers to adjust filter settings when you do **Save As** on a csv file.

To get there check the box "Edit filter settings" in the Save As dialog. After pressing the save button a "Textexport" dialog will show up where you can select the text codec among other things.